# Change dynamically className in jsx element

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to when I change the value of pros.show (simply it gives true or false), then add class to  element dynamically. How could I do that using sideDrawer method?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './SideDrawer.css';

class SideDrawer extends Component {
    state = {  }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

    }

   sideDrawer = () => {
        let drawerClasses = ['side-drawer'];
        if(this.props.show) {
            drawerClasses.push('open');
        }

        return drawerClasses.join(" ");
    };


    render() { 

        return ( 
            <nav className={this.sideDarwer}>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Check Paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Add Paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Modify Paper</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
         );
    }
}

export default SideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

```
    <nav className={`side-drawer ${this.props.show && 'open'}`}>
```